# moment checking date validate

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

How can I check the validity of the date?
whether she passed or not.
I've tried everything. And I read the documentation. But it's not working for me.
I tried it this way:

```
 if ('2023-03-03 12:22:16' > moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss')) {
            
        } else {
            return reply('Your current subscription has not expired. Wait for it to expire')
        }
```

tried to use: `isBetwen, isBefore` i.e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without the use of moment.js, just with native JavaScript methods.

You can't compare date strings, you need to convert them to timestamps and compare two timestamps. In your case you can do this:

```
if (new Date('2023-03-03 12:22:16').getTime() > new Date().getTime()) {
  ...
} else {
  return reply('Your current subscription has not expired. Wait for it to expire');
}
```